# How to solve $\int_\mathbb{R}\frac{\varepsilon}{(\mu-\lambda)^2+\varepsilon^2}f(\mu)\,d\mu$?

Tags: integration

I try to solve the following integral, $$-\int_\mathbb{R}\frac{\varepsilon}{(\mu-\lambda)^2+\varepsilon^2}f(\mu)\,d\mu, $$
with $\varepsilon >0$, $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, $\mu\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f\in\mathcal{C}^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$. I tried to use integration by parts with $$v'=\frac{\varepsilon}{(\mu-\lambda)^2+\varepsilon^2} \Rightarrow v = \arctan\left(\frac{\mu-\lambda}{\varepsilon}\right) $$
$$ u=f(\mu)\Rightarrow u'=f'(\mu) .$$
With this I got, $$-\int_\mathbb{R}\frac{\varepsilon}{(\mu-\lambda)^2 + \varepsilon^2} f(\mu)\,d\mu = -\left(\left[\arctan\left(\frac{\mu-\lambda}{\varepsilon}\right)f(\mu)\right]-\int_{\mathbb{R}} \arctan\left(\frac{\mu-\lambda}{\varepsilon}\right)f'(\mu) \, d\mu\right) $$
Now the first part of the RHS is zero because $f$ is compactly supported. My problem is that I don't know how to proceed with the remaining part. I tried integration by parts here as well but failed.
Now my question is wether I have overlooked something or my previous calculations are wrong.

Comment: Other than belonging to $C_c^\infty(\mathbf R)$ the function $f$ is arbitrary. What do you mean by "solve"?

Comment: @UmbertoP. yes the function is arbitrary in the other aspects. With solve i mean that I want to calculate the integral as accurately as possible. So I want to get an expression with f.

Comment: The integral at the top of the question is an expression with $f$. Can you be more explicit about the form you are looking for?

Comment: @UmbertoP. Yeah sorry. I want to have something like $-\pi f(\lambda)$. Maybe there is a remainder term, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Since $f$ is bounded,
$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int_{\mathbb R}
 \frac \epsilon {(\mu - \lambda)^2 + \epsilon^2} f(\mu) d\mu =
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int_{\mathbb R}
 \frac {f(\epsilon u + \lambda)} {u^2 + 1} du =
\int_{\mathbb R} \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}
 \frac {f(\epsilon u + \lambda)} {u^2 + 1} du.$$

Answer (score 1):

just some tips

If I understand correctly you want to evaluate $I(\lambda)=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int_{\mathbb R}  \frac \epsilon {(\mu - \lambda)^2 + \epsilon^2} f(\mu) \, d\mu$ (i.e. $\epsilon$ is infinitesimal). You can rewrite integral in the form:
$$I(\lambda)=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \frac{-i}{2}\int_{\mathbb R}  f(\mu) \, d\mu \left(\frac 1 {(\mu - \lambda) -i \epsilon}-\frac 1 {(\mu - \lambda) +i \epsilon}\right) $$

So, $\epsilon$ in fact define the way around the pole $\mu=\lambda$ - which of poles "plays". If you close your contour in upper-half on the complex plane the first term contributes (and will give $\frac{-i}{2}2\pi{i}f(\lambda)=\pi{f}(\lambda)$ - we go counter clockwise); if in the lower half-plane - the second (and will give $\frac{i}{2}(-2\pi{i})f(\lambda)=\pi{f}(\lambda)$ - we go clockwise).

How you close the contour (integration over big half-circle) depends on behaviour of $f(\mu)$ - which is often defined by some physical considerations.